# Exchange 2007 Offline Address Book not updating

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

Client computers running Outlook 2007 in cached mode are not getting updates to the OAB. When we send/receive-> download address book/ full changes, Outlook appears to download the address book with no errors, however the oab does not update. If we turn off cached mode, the GAL is correct.

the environment was migrated from a 2003 server, which is no longer available.

we have re-created the OAB and set the newly created OAB as default.

when we run get-offlineaddressbook | fl , it shows the OAB as being located on our exchange 2007 server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance your OAB is not generating properly anymore. Do you have anything related in your server's event log?

There is a good walkthrough in this [blog entry from corelan](http://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/05/22/fixing-exchange-2007-offline-address-book-generation-oalgen-and-distribution-issues/) which should help you with troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd ask is your Exchange 2007 server actualy your OAB generation server? If not, move the OAB generation to it.

What's the distribution method of your OAB - web based or public folders? If you're using public folders, is the DB mounted and is replication healthy?

Diagnostic logging is very helpful with OAB generation issues. Crank the logging level up and monitor the Event Log - it often tells you what part is failing and you can investigate further from there.